# keylistener and timer for game

Tags: java, time, timer, keylistener

how can I use a key listener for this project?
I want to see the next char after entering the right char...
I used random letters for my alphabet.
and right entered char will plus 5sec to progress bar and it helps u to survive more in game.
and how can I set its time up to like first 5 sec = show 5 let, second 5 sec = show 6 let...?

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class singleplayer {

public JFrame frame;
private Timer pt ;
public String rndchar() {

    Random r1 = new Random();
    int b = r1.nextInt(26)+97;
    char show1 =(char) b;

    Random r2 = new Random();
    int l = r2.nextInt(26)+65;
    char show2 =(char) l;

    if (r1.nextInt(2) % 2 == 0 )
    {
        return show1+"";
    }
    else if (r2.nextInt(2) % 2 == 1)
    {
        return show2+"";
    }
    return show2+"";        

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                singleplayer window = new singleplayer();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public singleplayer() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(400, 180, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    desktopPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Font rndchar = new Font("Old English Text MT", Font.PLAIN, 50);
    JLabel lblAlphabet = new JLabel();
    lblAlphabet.setText(rndchar());
    lblAlphabet.setBounds(185, 168, 360, 94);
    desktopPane.add(lblAlphabet);
    lblAlphabet.setFont(rndchar);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    progressBar.setValue(100);
    progressBar.setBounds(25, 78, 146, 14);
    desktopPane.add(progressBar);

     pt = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
            progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getValue()-1);
            if (progressBar.getValue() == 0) {
                lblAlphabet.setText("Game Over !");
            }   
        }
    });
        pt.start();
}
}
```

Comment: I assume you have already googled key listeners, found a tutorial or two and just couldn't get them to work with your code?

Comment: i had googled but i cant fix it with my project specially the last part (first 5 sec...)

Comment: yeah well that last part is not really clear to me. what are lets for example? :D is 5 let more than 3 huffs?

Comment: its a game that will show random letters in real time, and it should show letters in its rule which is from sec 0-5 each 1 sec it will show 1 letter - 5-10 each 1 sec 2 letter - 10-15 each 0.9sec 1 sec and untill the end.

Comment: Alright but that makes this two very different questions. Maybe split them up? One is how to use a key listener and the other is how to use some sort of timer?

Comment: no buddy see this:

Comment: see my next question